# Searching for postcode when space exists or does not exist

Tags: sql

Im running a sql search query to bring up records that match a post code
say i have a postcode:

'CB4 1AB'

if the database has (with and without a space)

- cb41ab
- cb4 1ab

or i search with (with and without a space)

- cb41ab
- cb4 1ab

i want it to bring back the record

How can i do it?

```
select addr1, addr2, postcode 
from addresses p
where p.postcode LIKE 'cb%'
```

Thanks

Comment: Just replace the space when searching?  `where REPLACE(p.postcode, ' ', '') LIKE 'cb%'`?

Comment: What is the Output you except...? Place the sample output in your Post, Then it will avoid confusions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
select addr1, addr2, postcode 
from addresses p
where replace(p.postcode, ' ', '') LIKE 'cb41ab'
```

Answer (score 2):

So, it sounds like you're going for this.  Expanding on other answers:

```
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(50)
SET @input = 'CB4 1AB'

SELECT addr1, addr2, postcode
FROM addresses p
WHERE REPLACE(p.postcode, ' ', '') = REPLACE(@input, ' ', '')
```

EDIT: I removed the "LIKE" since this should cover all above cases.

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear to me so I have multiple answers:
a) If you look for a specific UK post code, do it like this: LIKE 'cb4%1ab'. Both versions will return ("spaced" and wo. space ones).
b) If you use LIKE 'cb%' that won't give any trouble either. Field will return the value either it has or has no space in it.
c) If you want to find a post code, *specifically having* or *not having* space say LIKE 'cb4_1%' for post codes with space and LIKE 'cb41%' for post codes not having space - or even better to look for field size instead (6 chars long or 7) so LENGTH([fieldname]) = 6 [or 7]
d) The user enters a postcode and you don't know if value has or has no space in it: I'd say code revise is needed, shouldn't be sorted out on SQL/Server side. If it's not possible REPLACE added by others is just fine. If both "d" and "a" is true in your case, use REPLACE to change space into "%", so whatever the input was and whatver is stored in db (field value has or has no space), you'll get the result
Last but not least, just an advice: if you have the chance to 'uniformize' the field's value, do it (set field max length to 6 and/or update the table and remove space from values)
Hope this helps!

[EDIT: added 'd' option :) ]